# React Input Cannot Click Into

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog

Here is the [Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-architecture-jz30nl) - ignore the name, that's autogenerated.

I'm attempting to build a modal from scratch, mostly for learning, but also for control of style. I cannot seem to figure out why I can't click into my input fields. I can tab into them, but I can't click in them. I know I need to eventually add a value and onChange handler, but for now I just want to click into the fields.

When I used Bootstrap, these worked fine. But I want to learn how to do it myself.

Additionally, I can't seem to figure out how to stop the modal closing when clicking on the modal dialog. I just want it to close when I click the background.

The ReactPortal component is a bit of copy paste, but it's actually what I needed to get the modal background to cover the whole layout.

There's more files, feel free to look through them. I was just replicating what I've built on VS Code and just copied it all into Codesandbox to see if it could help me find what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried different libraries and they have worked, but I can't seem to get my own code to work even after following tutorials, reading blogs, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like another library is using the same css classes that you are using in modal.js, which is interfering with the behavior you are going for.

I prefixed the css classes in modal.css with custom- (.custom-modal for example) and updated the corresponding elements in modal.js, which made the inputs become clickable. You can change the class names to whatever you want, as long as another library isn't already using that name. One way to avoid this in the future that I have seen is to prefix all css classes that you create with the name of the app you are making (.my-app-modal for example).

Comment: You are a life saver! How did you figure that out if you don't mind me asking. That's a skill I clearly need!

Comment: @MPiland The key was to simplify the problem as much as possible. I kept removing files/components, until the entire react app only consisted of the modal. It was still having the same issue, so I started removing libraries that weren't being used anymore, and all of a sudden, it started working, but it LOOKED different. I put 2 and 2 together and realized that the css was probably the issue. The rest of it is experience, but you would probably have a lot more ammo to tackle the problem if you knew that libraries were messing with the css.

Comment: Nice! I'll try that method next time. Thank you!